# Resize window (in center screen) wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i need open in all work area

```
this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
```

but, window not center location in the screen, how i can location my window in center screen?

Comment: You need to **refine your question**. As you can see by the vague answers, your question is not sufficiently describing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx)

In XAML

```
<Window WindowState="Maximised">
// ...
</Window>
```

In Code-behind

```
MyWindow mw = new MyWindow();
mw.WindowState = WindowState.Maximised;
```

Comment: but window is not location worl area, he is full screen

Answer (score 1):

write like this .
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

Comment: Please explain your answers more fully, they will be more useful to the OP and others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [WindowStartupLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx)

**UPDATED**

If I use...

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
    this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
    this.Top = 0;
    this.Left = 0;
}
```

Without WindowStartupLocation, the window is centered and fills the screen

Comment: Maybe you should use this.Top=0; this.Left=0;